# Google OAuth Credentials URI to accept non-standard virtualhost name like - "https://q.localhost"?

Tags: oauth, google-signin

I am setting up Google's OAuth credentials.

I have set up my local machine to use the virtual host name of q.localhost, and I access the local site by using https://q.localhost

When I enter https://q.localhost for the URI, google gives me the error of: "The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid"

Is there a way to get the credentials to accept "https://q.localhost"?

I can change everything back to use just localhost, which it accepts, but I would rather not if I don't have to as there were reasons why I did this in the first place...

Comment: What type of application is this and what language are you using?

Comment: php application for a Q&A site with members, etc. - in development mode now.   Don't think this should have bearing on Google's credentials, as they never ask these details.  Facebook allows you to register whatever url address you create, but Google doesn't seem to.  https://localhost works is accepted, but any https://xxx.localhost does not seem to be accepted.